# How to filter a table with a row containing multiple ID types

Tags: r

I have a database that has a table **DF** like this

```
    ID Average
   A_1     1.5
   B_2     1.8
   C_3     2.9
   B_1     8.0
   C_4    12.0
   D_1     3.0
   B_4     6.0
   C_1     3.4
   D_2     5.6
   F_1     7.8
```

Below are the contents of an excel file that I import as a df called **DF_RAW** in my R script

```
  ID_Raw Measure
       A  Length
   B,C,D Breadth
       A  Length
   B,C,D Breadth
   B,C,D Breadth
       F   Width
```

I am trying to write a SQL query that filters the contents in DF according to the different types of ID's in DF_RAW

```
ID_types <- as.character(unique(DF_RAW$ID_Raw))
ID_config <- ID_types[1] #"A"
```

Now, the ID is A

```
SELECT * FROM   DF 
WHERE  ID LIKE ( '",ID_config,"%' )
```

This works fine and I get my desired output but when I change the index to

```
ID_config <- ID_types[2] #"B,C,D"
```

It returns no data. My desired output is

```
    ID Average
   B_2     1.8
   C_3     2.9
   B_1     8.0
   C_4    12.0
   D_1     3.0
   B_4     6.0
   C_1     3.4
   D_2     5.6
```

How to achieve this desired output using R?

Comment: Why the R tag when you want a SQL answer? Why both Oracle and MySql? Which one are you using?

Comment: Sorry. Just edited it. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Kind of difficult to ascertain what you're looking for, but try `IN` instead of `LIKE`.

Comment: @Sharath . . . Actually, I have the opposite question.  You are showing R code and doing the work in R.  Why do you have SQL tags?

Comment: That said, are you building the SQL query in R? An easy solution might be to use R to break apart the comma-separated values you import from Excel.

Comment: I use an SQL query in R to pull data from a database that has the DF table and hence I am looking at modifying my SQL query part.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, This is because I want to edit my SQL query that I use in R. I am just looking at an optimized sql query that can handle my task.

Comment: As Gregor suggested a good start would be to split the comma separated list first. you dont have any id's that start "B,C,D" but you do have "B" "C" and "D"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `R`, if we use `sqldf` library, create the string with `sprintf` and `gsub`

```
library(sqldf)
ID_config <- ID_types[2]
ID_confign <- sprintf("SELECT * FROM DF WHERE ID LIKE '%%%s%%'", 
 gsub(",", "%' OR ID LIKE '%", ID_config))

sqldf(ID_confign)
#   ID Average
#1 B_2     1.8
#2 C_3     2.9
#3 B_1     8.0
#4 C_4    12.0
#5 D_1     3.0
#6 B_4     6.0
#7 C_1     3.4
#8 D_2     5.6
```